# Why does numpy.r_ use brackets instead of parentheses?

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy.r_, .c_ and .s_ are the only Python functions I've come across that take arguments in square brackets rather than parentheses. Why is this the case? Is there something special about these functions? Can I make my own functions that use brackets (not that I want to; just curious)?

For example, the proper syntax is:

```
    np.r_['0,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

I would have expected it to be:

```
    np.r_('0,2', [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any Python class can be made so that its instances accept either or both notation: it will accept parens by implementing a function called `__call__`, and brackets by implementing `__getitem__`.

`np.r_` happens to be of a class that implements `__getitem__` to do fancier things than its usual. That is, the class of `r_` (called `np.lib.index_tricks.RClass`) does something like this:

```
class RClass:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        # r_ fancyness
```

Likely, this was done so that it can take advantage of slice notation - eg, when you have a list (or np array or any other object implementing this protocol) `l`, and you do:

```
l[:5]
```

, Python automatically creates a `slice` object to pass to `__getitem__`.

This syntax *doesn't* work with `__call__` - a user would have to create the slice explicitly, by doing `l(slice(5))`.

Note that `__call__` can take whatever arguments you like; while `__getitem__` always takes exactly one argument: when you do something like `my_array[1:3, 2:5]`, Python passes in a single *tuple* of slices. But, as you see with `r_`, the contents aren't restricted to numbers and slices - similarly to any other function, Python will happily pass in any object and leave it to the class to work out what it means.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me that this is just standard syntax.

Comment: However, I don't understand the purpose, since the slices are inside the passed arrays. 

Also, if there is an advantage to this, why don't we see it more often?

Comment: @KennethD'Amica You would have to pass in `slice(start, stop, step)` to the function call as the only other alternative. `__getitem__` is the only way to achieve this, it is **not** an advantage, this is rather hacky way to do this but it was built simply for convenience and it's really only needed when testing out code