# numpy._r with a list

Tags: python, numpy

If I have some numpy arrays, say a and b. We can do the following `data = numpy.r_[a, b]`. However if I have a list `L = [a, b]` how can I use `numpy.r` ? Soemthing like `data = numpy.r_(L)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the list to a tuple because `__getitem__` (ie, `[...]`) accepts a single argument (and giving it a list confuses `r_`):

```
np.r_[tuple(L)]
```

There's more information about `r_`, brackets and parenthesis in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16755482/1191119).