# numpy.r_ is not a function. What is it?

Tags: python, function, numpy

According to the numpy/scipy doc on `numpy.r_` [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), it is "not a function, so takes no parameters".

If it is not a function, what is the proper term for "functions" such as `numpy.r_`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a class instance (aka an object):

```
In [2]: numpy.r_
Out[2]: <numpy.lib.index_tricks.RClass at 0x1923710>
```

A class is a construct which is used to define a distinct *type* - as such a class allows *instances* of itself. Each instance can have properties (member/instance variables and methods).

One of the methods a class can have is the `__getitem__` method, this is called whenever you append `[something,something...something]` to the name of the instance. In the case of the `numpy.r_` instance the method returns a numpy array.

Take the following class for example:

```
class myClass(object)
    def __getitem__(self,i)
        return i*2
```

Look at these outputs for the above class:

```
In [1]: a = myClass()

In [2]: a[3]
Out[2]: 6

In [3]: a[3,4]
Out[3]: (3, 4, 3, 4)
```

I am calling the `__getitem__` method of myClass (via the `[]` parentheses) and the `__getitem__` method is returning (the contents of a list * 2 in this case)- it is *not* the class/instance behaving as a function - it is the `__getitem__` function of the `myClass` instance which is being called.

On a final note, you will notice that to instantiate `myClass` I had to do `a = myClass()` whereas to get an instance of `RClass` you use `numpy.r_` This is because numpy instantiates `RClass` and binds it to the name numpy.r_ itself. [This is the relevant line in the numpy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6c729b4423857850e6553cf6c2d0fc8b026036dd/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L437). In my opinion this is rather ugly and confusing!

Comment: It's actually an instance of `RClass` rather than a class itself.

Comment: @RobertKern You are correct of course, I have amended my answer to reflect that.

Comment: can you explain for others around here what the difference is between an instance of a class and a class itself?

Comment: Sure, done, let me know if you think it needs further clarification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16755528/901925 explains that `__getitem__` is used instead of `__call__` to take advantage of `slice` notation.

Comment: `numpy.r_` does not instantiate an `RClass`.  It references an instance that already exists.  `myr=type(np.r_)()` creates a new instance, one with new id. But I don't think there is a practical reason to do so.

Answer (score 46):

I would argue that for all purposes `r_` **is** a function, but one implemented by a clever hack using different syntax. Mike already explained how `r_` is in reality not a function, but a class instance of `RClass`, which has `__getitem__` implemented, so that you can use it as `r_[1]`. The cosmetic difference is that you use square brackets instead of curved ones, so you are not doing a function call, but you are actually indexing the object. Although this is technically true, for all purposes, it works just like a function call, but one that allows some extra syntax not allowed by a normal function.

The motivation for creating `r_` probably comes from Matlab's syntax, which allows to construct arrays in a very compact way, like `x = [1:10, 15, 20:10:100]`. To achieve the same in numpy, you would have to do `x = np.hstack((np.arange(1,11), 15, np.arange(20,110,10)))`. Using colons to create ranges is not allowed in python, but they do exist in the form of the slice notation to index into a list, like `L[3:5]`, and even `A[2:10, 20:30]` for multi-dimensional arrays. Under the hood, these index notation gets transformed to a call to the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method of the object, where the colon notation gets transformed into a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) object:

```
In [13]: class C(object):
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, x):
    ...:         print x

In [14]: c = C()

In [15]: c[1:11, 15, 20:110:10]
(slice(1, 11, None), 15, slice(20, 110, 10))
```

The `r_` object 'abuses' this fact to create a 'function' that accepts slice notation, which also does some additional things like concatenating everything together and returning the result, so that you can write `x = np.r_[1:11, 15, 20:110:10]`. The "Not a function, so takes no parameters" in the documentation is slightly misleading ...

Comment: In one sense it comes down to having `__getitem__` method and a `__call__` method.  `np.array`, `np.r_` and `[]` have the former, a function has the later.  In fact any object is callable if it has a `__call__`.