# Numpy savetxt to csv with integer integer string

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have three lists which I would like to save in a **csv** file using the `savetxt` function from numpy.

list1, list2 and list3 all have the same length with a single value.

list1,list2 are integer values, list3 has string values

So in the end it should look like this **column1=list1 column2=list2 column3=list3**

**This works for me if list3 is integer,too. It doesn´t work now, because list3 is a string.**

How can I realize this with list3 as a string and find a workaround for `c_`?

```
savetxt('data/result.csv', c_(list1,list2,list3), delimiter=',', fmt='%d, %d, %d', 
            header='Name,Value,Value2', comments = '')
```

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Your `fmt` string tries to format them all as integers.

Comment: I know about this, but it doesnt work. TypeError: `'CClass' object is not callable`

Comment: `c_` does something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601001/numpy-r-is-not-a-function-what-is-it http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html

Comment: If the data is in python lists, why not use the `csv` module?  E.g. `f = open('result.csv', 'w'); wrtr = csv.writer(f); wrtr.writerows(zip(list1, list2, list3)); f.close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is this:

```
c_(list1, list2, list3)
```

[`c_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) is a quirky object that is used by *indexing* it instead of *calling* it.  When you call it, you get the error mentioned in the comments:

```
In [42]: c_(list1, list2, list3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-8fcbef857684> in <module>()
----> 1 c_(list1, list2, list3)

TypeError: 'CClass' object is not callable
```

Instead, use square brackets, so you are indexing:

```
In [44]: c_[list1, list2, list3]
Out[44]: 
array([['10', '15', 'foo'],
       ['20', '25', 'bar'],
       ['30', '35', 'baz']], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Note that it creates an array with dtype `'|S3'`.  That is, all the elements in the array have been converted to strings.  To save this with `savetxt`, use `fmt='%s, %s, %s'`:

```
In [45]: savetxt('result.csv', c_[list1, list2, list3], fmt='%s, %s, %s')

In [46]: !cat result.csv
10, 15, foo
20, 25, bar
30, 35, baz
```

Also, instead of `c_[list1, list2, list3]`, you could use `zip(list1, list2, list3)`.  Then the `savetxt` function will handle converting that argument to an array.

```
In [57]: list1 = [100000, 200000, 300000]

In [58]: savetxt('result.csv', zip(list1, list2, list3), fmt='%s, %s, %s')

In [59]: !cat result.csv
100000, 15, foo
200000, 25, bar
300000, 35, baz
```

Apparently `c_` doesn't do a good job figuring out the appropriate lengths of the strings:

```
In [60]: c_[list1, list2, list3]
Out[60]: 
array([['100', '15', 'foo'],
       ['200', '25', 'bar'],
       ['300', '35', 'baz']], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

---

By the way, your data is not already in a numpy array, so I don't think you gain much by using `savetxt` instead of the standard library [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).  For example,

```
In [61]: import csv

In [62]: with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
   ....:     wrtr = csv.writer(f)
   ....:     wrtr.writerows(zip(list1, list2, list3))
   ....:     

In [63]: !cat result.csv
100000,15,foo
200000,25,bar
300000,35,baz
```

Comment: We are getting closer, I have tried this, thanks. But all my integer numbers 10000 are converted to 1.

Comment: all my integers are now 1-9. This starts when using `c_[]` `transformed_matrix =c_[list1,list2,list3]` `print(transformed_matrix[1]` => `['1' '2' 'b']`

Comment: I updated my answer to suggest using `zip(list1, list2, list3)` instead of `c_[list1, list2, list3]`.

Comment: Just one question, I have done one csv file manually with integers and replacing the last column with string manually. And now compared it to %s %s %s. How come this file is larger?

Comment: newfile : `100000, 69852, s`  vs `100000,69852,s` it has a space between

Comment: Use the `fmt` argument to control the spacing, e.g. `%s,%s,%s` vs. `%s, %s, %s`

Comment: THANKS! ALL WORKING. SAVED MY DAY! THANK YOU