# equivalent of numpy.c_ in julia

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, julia

Hi I am going through the book https://nnfs.io/ but using JuliaLang (it's a self-challenge to get to know the language better and use it more often.. rather than doing the same old same in Python..)

I have come across a part of the book in which they have custom wrote some function and I need to recreate it in JuliaLang...

source: https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/

**python**

```
N = 100 # number of points per class
D = 2 # dimensionality
K = 3 # number of classes
X = np.zeros((N*K,D)) # data matrix (each row = single example)
y = np.zeros(N*K, dtype='uint8') # class labels
for j in range(K):
  ix = range(N*j,N*(j+1))
  r = np.linspace(0.0,1,N) # radius
  t = np.linspace(j*4,(j+1)*4,N) + np.random.randn(N)*0.2 # theta
  X[ix] = np.c_[r*np.sin(t), r*np.cos(t)]
  y[ix] = j
# lets visualize the data:
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=40, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.show()
```

my **julia** version so far....

```
N = 100 # Number of points per class
D = 2   # Dimensionality
K = 3   # Number of classes

X = zeros((N*K, D))
y = zeros(UInt8, N*K)


# See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.range

for j in range(0,length=K)
    ix = range(N*(j), length = N+1)
    
    radius = LinRange(0.0, 1, N)
    theta = LinRange(j*4, (j+1)*4, N) + randn(N)*0.2
    X[ix] = ????????

end
```

notice the `???????` area because I am now trying to decipher if Julia has an equivalent for this numpy function

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html

Any help is appreciated.. or just tell me if I need to write something myself

Comment: You can try to write `for` loop which does what you want instead of searching for a function. Sometimes direct approach is the best one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a special object to provide nice syntax for column concatanation. In Julia this is just built into the language hence you can do:

```
julia> a=[1,2,3];        
                         
julia> b=[4,5,6];        
                                                
julia> [a b]             
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:       
 1  4                    
 2  5                    
 3  6
```

For your case the Julian equivalent of `np.c_[r*np.sin(t), r*np.cos(t)]` should be:

```
[r .* sin.(t)  r .* cos.(t)]
```

To understand Python's motivation you can also have a look at :
[numpy.r_ is not a function. What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601001/numpy-r-is-not-a-function-what-is-it)

Comment: brilliant.. once i solve my other problem I think I am all set!  thanks for the heads up..

Comment: Technically this differs from `np.c_` in that it concatenates along the second axis, not the last axis. But if your arrays are at most 2D then it's fine.

Comment: @BallpointBen according to docs, `np.c_` only works along the second axis.. you're maybe thinking of `np.r_` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html "Translates slice objects to concatenation along the second axis."

Comment: @Erik "arrays will be stacked along their last axis after being upgraded to at least 2-D..." I think this means that arrays of dimension at most 2 will be concatenated along the 2nd dimension (padding with singleton dimensions if necessary), but arrays of higher dim will be concatenated along their last axis. But it's not entirely clear to me either way.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of `numpy.c_` would seem to be horizontal concatenation, which you can do with either the `hcat` function or with (e.g.) simply `[a b]`. Fixing a few other issues with the translation so far, we end up with

```
N = 100 # Number of points per class
D = 2   # Dimensionality
K = 3   # Number of classes

X = zeros(N*K, D)
y = zeros(UInt8, N*K)

for j in range(0,length=K)
    ix = (N*j+1):(N*(j+1))
        
    radius = LinRange(0.0, 1, N)
    theta = LinRange(j*4, (j+1)*4, N) + randn(N)*0.2
    X[ix,:] .= [radius.*sin.(theta) radius.*cos.(theta)]
    y[ix] .= j
end
# visualize the data:
using Plots
scatter(X[:,1], X[:,2], zcolor=y, framestyle=:box)
```

[image: resulting spiral plot]

Comment: wow.. I accepted the other answer.. but you have not only provided a fix for my first problem here.. but you also solved this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68228564/error-attempting-to-index-using-unitrange-on-vector-in-julia feel free to post there and I will accept that answer there