# Error attempting to index using UnitRange on Vector in Julia

Tags: julia

I am attempting to translate some Python code into Julia.. but having trouble looking for an example where I have a range that I can then apply to a Matrix or vector to index upon... here's my code

source: https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/

**python**

```
N = 100 # number of points per class
D = 2 # dimensionality
K = 3 # number of classes
X = np.zeros((N*K,D)) # data matrix (each row = single example)
y = np.zeros(N*K, dtype='uint8') # class labels
for j in range(K):
  ix = range(N*j,N*(j+1))
  r = np.linspace(0.0,1,N) # radius
  t = np.linspace(j*4,(j+1)*4,N) + np.random.randn(N)*0.2 # theta
  X[ix] = np.c_[r*np.sin(t), r*np.cos(t)]
  y[ix] = j
# lets visualize the data:
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=40, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.show()
```

**julia**

```
N = 100 # Number of points per class
D = 2   # Dimensionality
K = 3   # Number of classes

X = zeros((N*K, D))
y = zeros(UInt8, N*K)


# See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.range

for j in range(0,length=K)
    #println("\n\nj=", j)
    #println("N*(j) = ", N*(j),"  N*(j+1) = ", N*(j+1))
    ix = range(N*(j), length = N+1)
    
    # See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.LinRange
    radius = LinRange(0.0, 1, N)
    theta = LinRange(j*4, (j+1)*4, N) + randn(N)*0.2
    
    
    y[ix] = j

end

Pkg.add("Plots")
using Plots
```

the part that it doesn't like seems to be this `y[ix]`

```
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 300-element Vector{UInt8} at index [0:100]
Stacktrace:
 [1] throw_boundserror(A::Vector{UInt8}, I::Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}})
   @ Base ./abstractarray.jl:651
 [2] checkbounds
   @ ./abstractarray.jl:616 [inlined]
 [3] _setindex!
   @ ./multidimensional.jl:886 [inlined]
 [4] setindex!(A::Vector{UInt8}, v::Int64, I::UnitRange{Int64})
   @ Base ./abstractarray.jl:1267
 [5] top-level scope
   @ ~/ex03.04-toy-spiral-data.jl:21
in expression starting at /ex03.04-toy-spiral-data.jl:11
```

seems my ix is of type

```
julia> typeof(ix)
UnitRange{Int64}
```

is this wrong or do I need to switch from a vector to matrix or ?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so this is just a zero-vs-one indexing issue. Completing the Julia code, we then have

```
N = 100 # Number of points per class
D = 2   # Dimensionality
K = 3   # Number of classes

X = zeros(N*K, D)
y = zeros(UInt8, N*K)

for j in range(0,length=K)
    ix = (N*j+1):(N*(j+1))
        
    radius = LinRange(0.0, 1, N)
    theta = LinRange(j*4, (j+1)*4, N) + randn(N)*0.2
    X[ix,:] .= [radius.*sin.(theta) radius.*cos.(theta)]
    y[ix] .= j
end
# visualize the data:
using Plots
scatter(X[:,1], X[:,2], zcolor=y, framestyle=:box)
```

[image: resulting spiral plot]

Now as far as performance, while it almost certainly doesn't matter for this particular application, it's always fun do to optimize things, and this could be an instructive example so let's dive in.

We're actually not doing to bad here to start because `LinRange` is quite fast and can be stack-allocated (as opposed to heap- if it were a full `Array`):

```
function spiral(N,D,K)
    X = zeros(N*K, D)
    y = zeros(UInt8, N*K)

    for j in range(0,length=K)
        ix = (N*j+1):(N*(j+1))
            
        radius = LinRange(0.0, 1, N)
        theta = LinRange(j*4, (j+1)*4, N) + randn(N)*0.2
        X[ix,:] .= [radius.*sin.(theta) radius.*cos.(theta)]
        y[ix] .= j
    end
    return X, y
end
```

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark spiral(100,2,3)

BechmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  12.479 μs …   9.867 ms  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 99.39%
 Time  (median):     14.618 μs               ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   17.741 μs ± 132.348 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  10.48% ±  1.41%

   ▅█▃▇▆█▆▃▃▂                                                   
  ▄██████████▅▄▄▄▅▄▃▃▄▃▃▄▃▂▂▂▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▂▂▂▂▁▁▁▁▁▁ ▃
  12.5 μs         Histogram: frequency by time         30.1 μs <

 Memory estimate: 23.62 KiB, allocs estimate: 20.
```

However the `randn(N)` and subsequent construction of `theta` both do allocate `Array`s which are not reused, so if K were going to be very large that might add up, so in that case you might want to find a way either do that *in-place* or on the stack if this weren't just a one-off generation of testing data. One way to do this might include

```
function spiral(N,D,K)
    X = zeros(N*K, D)
    y = zeros(UInt8, N*K)

    r = LinRange(0.0, 1, N)
    @inbounds for j in 1:K
        θ = LinRange((j-1)*4, j*4, N)
        for i in 1:N
            θᵢ = θ[i] + 0.2*randn()
            δ = N*(j-1)
            X[δ+i,1] = r[i] * sin(θᵢ)
            X[δ+i,2] = r[i] * cos(θᵢ)
            y[δ+i] = j
        end
    end
    return X, y
end
```

which gives

```
julia> @benchmark spiral(100,2,3)
BechmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):   9.399 μs … 958.059 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     10.597 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   11.851 μs ±  17.765 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

   ▄█▇▆▅▄▁                                                      
  ▄███████▆▅▅▄▃▃▄▄▄▃▃▃▃▃▄▄▃▃▃▃▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▁▂▂▂▁▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂ ▃
  9.4 μs          Histogram: frequency by time         22.5 μs <

 Memory estimate: 5.20 KiB, allocs estimate: 2.
```

Not a huge speedup, but significantly fewer allocations. However, the fact that this second approach is faster at all may come as a surprise to folks coming from languages where `for` loops are slow. In Julia, just like in C or Fortran, loops are fast!

Now of course, if you really needed maximum performance, the solution as usual is Chris Elrod's [LoopVectorization.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSIMD/LoopVectorization.jl) and [VectorizedRNG.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSIMD/VectorizedRNG.jl), which will make full use of your CPU's SIMD vector registers (e.g. [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)):

```
using LoopVectorization, VectorizedRNG
function spiral_turbo(N,D,K)
    X = zeros(N*K, D)
    y = zeros(UInt8, N*K)
    randbuffer = zeros(N)

    r = LinRange(0.0, 1, N)
    for j in 1:K
        θ = LinRange((j-1)*4, j*4, N)
        # Fill random number buffer using VectorizedRNG
        randn!(local_rng(), randbuffer)
        # Fast inner loop using LoopVectorization
        @turbo for i in 1:N
            θᵢ = θ[i] + 0.2*randbuffer[i]
            δ = N*(j-1)
            X[δ+i,1] = r[i] * sin(θᵢ)
            X[δ+i,2] = r[i] * cos(θᵢ)
            y[δ+i] = j
        end
    end
    return X, y
end
```

which gives us about another 2x speedup

```
julia> @benchmark spiral_turbo(100,2,3)

BechmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 7 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  4.023 μs …  1.928 ms  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 99.45%
 Time  (median):     4.420 μs              ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   5.866 μs ± 37.774 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  12.59% ±  1.99%

  ▅▆▇█▇▅▄▃▂▂▂▂▃▂▂▂▁▁                                         ▂
  ██████████████████▇▇▆▇▆▆▆▆▅▅▆▆▄▅▆▄▇▇▇▇▇▆▅▅▅▅▄▄▄▂▄▂▅▂▄▄▃▃▄▄ █
  4.2 μs       Histogram: log(frequency) by time     10.2 μs <

 Memory estimate: 6.08 KiB, allocs estimate: 3.
```

Comment: thanks for helping me use Julia with this book https://nnfs.io/ , I am hoping to keep pushing and help give back so more people can approach JuliaLang!

Comment: Of course! Just added a few more details about performance and benchmarking just for fun