# What is the type of loc and iloc? (brackets vs parentheses)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm from C++ background and started learning python recently. I was studying about indexing and selecting data. I came across `.iloc[]` in the class `Series`, `DataFrame` and `Panel` in the pandas library. I couldn't understand what is `.iloc`? Is it function or an attribute ? Many times I mistakenly use `()` instead of `[]` and don't get the actual result (but it doesn't throw me an error).

Example:

```
In [43]: s = pd.Series(np.arange(5), index=np.arange(5)[::-1], dtype='int64')

In [44]: s[s.index.isin([2, 4, 6])]
Out[44]: 
4    0
2    2
dtype: int64

In [45]: s.iloc(s.index.isin([2,4,6]))
Out[45]: <pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer at 0x7f1e68d53978>

In [46]: s.iloc[s.index.isin([2,4,6])]
Out[46]: 
4    0
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Could anyone tell me reference where to study much more about such type of operators.

Comment: It is similar to numpy.r_ so these discussions might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755482/why-does-numpy-r-use-brackets-instead-of-parentheses  https://stackoverflow.com/q/18601001/2285236

Answer (score 6):

**The practical answer:**  You should think of `iloc` and `loc` as pandas extensions of the python list and dictionary respectively and treat them as lookups rather than function or method calls.  Thus, keeping with python syntax, always use `[]` rather than `()`.

```
>>> ser = pd.Series( { 'a':3, 'c':9 } )

>>> ser.loc['a']    # pandas dictionary syntax (label-based)
3
>>> ser.iloc[0]     # pandas list/array syntax (location-based)
3
```

It's basically the same for dataframes, just with an extra dimension to specify, and that's also where `iloc` and `loc` become more useful, but that's getting beyond the scope of this question.

**The deeper answer:**  If you are really trying to understand this at a deeper level, you need to understand `__getitem__`.  You could perhaps start [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) for some basics.  The answers in the [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601001/numpy-r-is-not-a-function-what-is-it) provided in the comments above by @ayhan are also excellent and quite relevant to your question.

Comment: Is there an existing library for using `loc`/`iloc`-like getters for hierarchical data consisting of raw dicts and lists - not pandas?

Comment: I mean an access model like Wolram Language where slicing, wildcards, and position/label indexing coexist for arbitrary expressions (eg multi-dim arrays and dict's). Given `data = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':4,'c':5}]` get 'a' and 'c'  like this: `data.myloc[_all_,['a','c']]`--> `['{'a':1,'c':3},{'a':4,'c':5}]` where `_all_` is a wildcard. (In WL a single key is dropped: `data.myloc[_all_,'a']` --> `[1,4]`).  slicing or numerical index should also work in place of  `_all_` and for arbitrary depth.

Comment: @alancalvitti  Sorry, no idea.  That's beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

`.iloc` is a class instance.

```
pd.DataFrame().iloc
Out[2]: <pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer at 0x97a2470>
```

Source: [Pandas Source Code - `indexing.py#L1626`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1626)